# Ordenar registros en vista admin

Tags: yii

Necesito que los registros que muestran listados en el CGridView de la vista admin estén ordenados de forma alfabética (ascendente o descendente) en cualquiera de los campos. ¿Me podrían ayudar?.

Comment: Amigo, estaría dichoso de apoyarte pero no está claro: ¿qué vista?, ¿qué modelo(s) usa?. Podrías incluir más información detallada sobre lo que buscas. Te recomiendo que veas [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y edites tu respuesta para que pueda brindarte apoyo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actualiza tu función `search()` en el modelo y agrega el código siguiente:

```
'criteria'=>$criteria,
//Agregar aqui

'sort'=>array(
    'defaultOrder'=>'order ASC',
),
```

Y dentro de la vista de admin cambia el `dataprovider` a:

```
'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
```

Fuente en ingles : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18822334/yii-change-default-order-in-cgridview

Comment: Funciona perfecto muchas gracias.